# Can PhpStorm take .htaccess files into account? (Or fullfill similar functionalities)

Tags: .htaccess, phpstorm

To access to a page in a project opened in PhpStorm in my local environment, I need to access `http://[ur]/[[filename]` instead `http://[ur]/`  (which I usually use).

This means that PhpStorm is not taking my `.htaccess` file into account. Is there a way that PhpStorm can take `.htaccess` into account?

Here I am talking about directory `DirectoryIndex`, but the same goes for `ErrorDocument` and more stuff that can be contained in .htaccess files.

EDIT: I know .htaccess is an Apache thing, I don't absolutely need .htaccess to work provided that I find a way to fulfill similar functionalities.

Comment: No, that makes little sense, actually, since these files are specific to the apache http server and operate on http requests, not on a php based application. So we are talking about two separate layers.

Comment: Maybe not precisely the .htaccess, but it would make sense to have something that fill some of their purpose, it would make sense to define which file is loaded on http requests, which is loaded on 404-or-other responses. Yet I don't see why exclude http requests from PhpStorm's considerations since it comes with a web server ( https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-built-in-web-server.html

Comment: Yes, it comes with a web server. But _a_ web server is not _the_ apache http server. There are many many different web servers you can chose from, they all behave different. Is it really wise to pick an arbitrary one as if that is some kind of "standard"? We all know where that leads to...

Comment: I can't imagine something pretending to be a web server and not handling things like 404-etc responses, yet some kind of rooting, specific files loading isn't something really advanced. I agree with you on more specifics functionnalities ...

I'm just trying to build a local environment that would run the same site I put online ... it's not obvious because my local machine is Windows 10 and my host uses Linux (and I think Apache) ...

Comment: I just hoped PhpStorm would make things easier and lighter than using things such as Wamp/Xampp but so far it looks like PhpStorm people tend to say that I need to adapt my code/project to their "development" environment ...

Comment: PhpStorm's built-in web server is a **simple* one; it's suitable for basic things mainly. It works with URLs like `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/path/file.html` where `PROJECT_NAME` part is required. It does take few things from .htaccess into an account, but only some. For a proper development use proper Apache/nginx/IIS/etc

Comment: Ok, thank you, I had just hoped PhpStorm had come with something more robust and simple for PHP ... such a when debugging web applications with Visual Studio, which works right away out of the box.

Comment: Why don't you simply setup a _real_ local web environment using a _real_ web server? This is not rocket science... True, it is more effort and less convenient under a MS-Windows environment compared to a Linux system, but it is possible. Many people did that.

Comment: Well ... some frameworks like Laravel/Symfony (for example) are fine with using PHP's own web server: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php -- they are using that behind their `artisan serve` (or whatever commands are). So they can run without "a proper" web server. If I need to develop a site /library that may work under IIS or nginx (where `.htaccess` is not used, and even current Apache versions do not recommend using it) .. why woudl I rely on Apache specific functionality?

Comment: @arkascha: I agree. I was simply hoping something more simple had come up for PHP (as I mentioned earlier, as debugging web applications with Visual Studio which only requires one click out-of-the-box ... I was hoping for something like that.) It is indeed not rocket science, but, also considering php developement is a marginal part of my activities (though I love it), the need to re-set/update everything and meeting new bugs each computer re/installation is something I'd hope to get rid of. Not yet the case, as I see.

Comment: @LazyOne: As I mentionned earlier, it's not so much .htaccess that I care about, but I can hardly imagine a web server that doesn't not have configuration similar to things like DirectoryIndex and  ErrorDocument .
What does Apache recommand to use instead?

Comment: Apache? No changes in  directives, but they do not recommend using .htaccess files (and it's turned off by default now, AFAIK). Instead they say to use main config file instead (so Apache does not read .htaccess files in every folder for every request). https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html -- check the note there. There were quite few security holes in some projects because it was relying on .htaccess support.

Comment: I see. Well most of my php sites end up on shared hosting where I usually can't acess main config files.

Comment: One uses a container for such things, docker for example. That gives you _exactly_ the same behavior of your development setup on all systems. And you can simply move your setup from system to system. Even between different operating systems.